# Esta and D160 denied - what can I change about my life?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, dual-nationality

I applied for a US tourist visa when I was only had a Brazilian passport, and they refused to give the visa. Now I have a British Passport and I have applied for the ESTA and D160 under 214. based on a tourism visitor and they also refused.

They said that my life has to change to prove that I have a roots in the UK.  I had tickets and hotel all paid in advance, and the immigration office  didn't even look it.

What should I do now to apply for the visa, as I'm a citizen in the UK I have job, I'm financially stable, and they keep saying that my life has to change since my last attempt.

Comment: D160 is a visa application, not an ESTA application. Did you apply for an ESTA and get denied, then apply for a visa? Please tell us exactly what the visa refusal said. And are you resident in the UK? Please edit this information into the question.

Comment: @DJClayworth That's what he means. Also, US visa refusals are not personalized unlike some other countries. The notice (214) will be generic mentioning a lack of ties.

Comment: @uberqe Even "lack of ties" will be more information than "your lifestyle has to change".

Comment: Hi basically I apply the ESTA and got denied and than I apply at the embassy base on tourist  visa , and they say I don't have enough ties in UK. They are thinking as I have immigrated to UK they think that I would do the same in US. But I have my hole life here also a British passport. can someone give a advise please. thank you

Comment: @DJClayworth as I said, they will give the exact same letter to EVERYONE refused under 214(b).